# Android Foreground Service For Location

Tags: android, service, gps, locationmanager

I need to make an app (spy app) that runs in background everytime and send location of the device to a server.

I don't want to use Google Api.

I tried to use Service, IntentService, Foreground service, Thread for socket etc etc, but when I close main activity it runs in background for sometimes then get killed.

How can I do this? 
Please I beg you, help me <3

Comment: A Service running without the user notice is the definition of a Service, are you checking if the Service is named in the Manifest of the application? How about checking how is being called? Can you share a little of code?

Comment: Yeah, it's named in the manifest, in fact when main activity is active it works. But when I kill main activity my service is killed because android kernel hate me :( ahahaha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah Let me Tell you, If you are having devices like Xiaomi, oppo, Vivo. You services will get killed by them. So no matter how hard you will try, it will be killed if you have not checked Autostart in settings. So you have to bound user to check it to make your app running in background.

So, there are many things you can do :

1. Restart your services in receiver of GCM service by sending push notification from server to the users in every given interval of time.

`

```
public class GcmNetworkTask extends GcmTaskService {

        @Override
        public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
            restartYourServiceHere();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

2. AlarmManager to restart your services.

   Bootcomplete receiver is used to start your services when system reboots

   public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Intent service = new Intent(context, Sample_service.class);
           context.startService(service);
   }
   ```

   }

then alarm manager in onstartCommand of service will do :

```
 intent = new Intent(this, ReceiverClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (40000), pendingIntent);
    return START_STICKY;
```

And then again a receiver class to catch even of alarm manager :

```
   public class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      context.startService(new Intent(context, Sample_service.class));

    }
}
```

3. Runnable thread will work if the activity gets paused but will stop if user destroys the activity.

For finding location you can use Google fusedLocationAPI, Location manager (If you are not getting gps you can get location by network also).

4. If anyone finding it too tricky, you can go with a hack : in OnDestroy of service restart your service as :

   `@Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           Intent startSeviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SampleService.class);
           startService(startSeviceIntent);
           super.onDestroy();
       }`

   And inside onStartCommand method fetch location and do what ever you want.

Comment: Hi! I fortunately don't use these devices!  Can you also tell me how to make it all? Also remember that I want that any activity stay on because users don't have to see anything... Thank you in advance ♥️

Comment: 4. point will surely solve your problem but i would recommend make another service extending GCMNetworkTask and in OnRunTask function check whether your service is running or not and if it is not then restart service from there....and it will work perfectly fine.

**NOTE: Don't forget to register your services in manifest**

Comment: Yes, I know that I've got to register it into manifest :) can you send me a zip with this project? Thank you :)

Comment: I will try if I get time but stack overflow is not all about getting whole code but patches of code or functions that can help you. According to that I have done everything for you.

Comment: For any further help contact me at prateekgupta22195@gmail.com

Comment: Yeah, You're right! Ahaha, it's only that I don't know how to start :P

In MainActivity I start my gps_service which use locationManager etc. 
I think that in MainActivity I've got to start also GCMNetworkTask (is this a service?)

If user close MainActivity my services got close all? Including GCMNetworkTask?

Comment: i can explain you end to end just reach me by email.. :) always happy to help

Comment: Ok, I send you an e-mail :)